Ebers Moll parameters for MPSA18 and AC128 BJT transistors
First of all, I should mention electronics is not my field so my problem might be trivial for you.
I'm currently working on my thesis and I need to model two BJT transistors: NPN MPSA18 and PNP AC128. Specifically, I need to use the Ebers Moll model but I can't find the right parameters anywhere. The parameters I need are commonly named alpha_r, alpha_f, and Ise and Isc(see picture below)
I found this collection of various BJT transistors parameters, including the two I need to model but I don't understand how to derive the parameters I need. I also found this guide to the Gummel Poon model parameters, but I'm still having a hard time understanding how to use it.
If you have any tips/links/ideas or if you just have the Ebers-Moll parameters for the MPSA18 and AC128 I'd really appreciate your help!
Image from Wikipedia


What you are referring to is the injection version. There are also two fully equivalent versions called he transport version and the hybrid-$\pi$ version. You may he able to find everything you need here. You should also get this book. Its also available new as a reprint at lulu.com.

The model you show was the very first Ebers-Moll model, now called the injection version. The transport version was developed later and was preferred, for a time, for reasons of computer simulation details and diffusion capacitance (which came later and helped boost the transport version.) The development and rise of the hybrid-\$\pi\$ version was due, overwhelmingly, to the easy transition from its non-linear to its linearized version. It was easier to teach. All three versions are mathematically equivalent, though.
You state you are looking for alpha_r, alpha_f, and Ise and Isc. But the diagram show in your question doesn't show the last two (well, I could be wrong but I don't see them there.) I have to guess what's meant. But I think this: \$\text{I}_{ES}\$ and \$\text{I}_{CS}\$. So you want \$\alpha_{_\text{F}}\$, \$\alpha_{_\text{R}}\$, \$\text{I}_{ES}\$ and \$\text{I}_{CS}\$.
There's a reciprocity relationship that has been observed experimentally and was readily proven for low-level injection cases by using Green's theorem:
$$\text{I}_{S}=\alpha_{_\text{F}}\,\text{I}_{ES}=\alpha_{_\text{R}}\,\text{I}_{CS}$$
Since you already know that \$\beta_{_\text{F}}=\frac{\alpha_{_\text{F}}}{1-\alpha_{_\text{F}}}\$ and that \$\beta_{_\text{R}}=\frac{\alpha_{_\text{R}}}{1-\alpha_{_\text{R}}}\$, I think you have everything you need now to take a Spice model and get your parameters. I'll assume you can take it from here.

thank you for taking the time to write this answer, that was very helpful!

@Sebastian Thank you for letting me know it helped you. :)
